# Стилизованный нумерованный список с точкой или как сделать составной content?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Стилизованный список очень удобно сделать через значение счетчика, но тогда в `content` можно поставить только порядковый номер элемента списка. Возможно ли сделать его составным? Хочу иметь на выходе число сразу после которого идет точка. Что-то вроде этого:

```
content:counter(olNum)+'.';
```

Но запись такого вида не дает никакого результата, и нумерация вовсе не работает.

Вот рабочий пример:

```css
ol {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  counter-reset: olNum;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

li:before {
  counter-increment: olNum;
  content: counter(olNum);
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: как не работает ? здесь работает же

Comment: @МаксимЛенский всё разобралась, пока вопрос писала! `+` был лишний!

Comment: ну тогда + в карму

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решение слишком простое, нужно без "+" в `content`'е:

```css
ol {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  counter-reset: olNum;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

li:before {
  counter-increment: olNum;
  content: counter(olNum)'.';
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ol>
```